# Why there are two different sites for bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What are the differences between these two bootstrap sites ?

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

http://getbootstrap.com/

Are there any advantages to use one over other?
Which one is recommended to download ?

Comment: getbootstrap.com is the newest version.

Comment: Bootstrap 2 vs 3: http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.3.2 is the older version. 3.x is the new version which is on the base url http://getbootstrap.com/